# Как определить, какое именно действие приводит к перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, отладка, инструменты-разработчика

Неизвестное действие из скрипта (думаю, асинхронное) приводит к пререзагрузке страницы.

Есть ли способ определить, какое именно действие и где?

Может, есть хотя бы способ отловить обращение к `window.location`?
Хотя не факт, что переход осуществляется таким образом.

Устраивает способ для любого браузера.

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/35635394/4928642)

Comment: Может что-то вроде повесить событие `beforeunload` в отладчике firefox запустить профилировщик, остановить его и посмотреть какая функция выполнялась перед `beforeunload`

Comment: @ReinRaus, интересная идея с порфилировщиком. А то про само событие я думал, но стектрейс из него достать не получилось.

Comment: @ReinRaus, всё оказалось проще :)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35635394/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Google Chrome:

1. Открыть вкладку Network
2. Отметить флажок Preserve log
3. После перехода на другую страницу найти соответствующий запрос
4. В столбце Initiator будет указан скрипт и строка в нём

PS: На основе [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35640260/4928642) от [@Kayce Basques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1669860/kayce-basques).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать установить обработчик события `beforeunload` и в профилировщике FireBug смотреть по времени выполнения длинный вызов перед этим обработчиком.
Тестовая страница состоит исключительно из этого:

```
<script>
var alarmSeeUp = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
};

window.addEventListener( "beforeunload", alarmSeeUp );

window.setTimeout( function() {
    location.reload();
}, 3000 );
</script>
```

В профилировщике хорошо видно по длинному времени выполнения вызывающую функцию, потому что я не спешу нажать кнопку в модальном окне браузера о разрешении перехода на страницу.
Восьмая строка кода `window.setTimeout( function() {`, что и требовалось найти.

[image: результат профилирования]

Comment: Всё проще, но штука всё равно полезная :)